# Issue with Pivots

Tags: excel

I am trying to recreate a pivot in another spreadsheet but it isn't letting me add more rows.  I am getting the following error when I try to add more than 1 row:

[image]

"This action will overlap the pivottable (table name) with data already in the sheet (sheet name)

How can I overcome this error to create the table?

Comment: The error itself is self-explanatory, please read carefully what it says. refer the last sentence it says.

Comment: But then it won't let me add the row to the table if I click no.

Comment: It wont, you need to add some place else. Otherwise it will overlap, that is why it is asking do you want to go ahead or not

Comment: But the additional rows were allowed in previous versions of the workbook